# Lost audio with real time "current time"

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm building a little audio player by myself. This player contains 7 buttons that when clicked add a song to my playlist, then you can press play to start the playing. Everything works fine except for this one particular thing: randomly the audio file I'm playing lost about 1 second, and it's very annoying.
I debugged the system and the problem seems disappear when I remove the real time visualization of the current time playing.
I thought it was a problem with the approximation, but I don't know how to fix.
It's like it's trying to "reach" the current time because it lost some value after the Math.floor
Here's my code:
**Code for the approximation + visualization:**

```
function infoSong2(){
    pippo = Math.floor(audioElement.currentTime);
        pluto = Math.floor(prova);
        var pippo2 = minutesModafaka(pippo);
        var pluto2 = minutesModafaka(pluto);

        $("#info").empty();
        $("#info").html(pippo2+"/"+pluto2);
}
function minutesModafaka(seconds){
        var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60) % 60;
        var seconds_left = seconds % 60;
        var time_formatted = (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds_left  < 10 ? "0" + seconds_left : seconds_left);
        return time_formatted;
    }
```

**Code for audio play:**

```
function playSong(){
        if(arraySongs.length == 0)
        {
            console.log("No songs selected!");
        }
        else{
        clicks++;
        console.log("CLICKS PLAY:"+clicks);
        if(clicks > 1)
        {
            pausePlaySong();
        }
        else{
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio/'+arraySongs[cont]+'.mp3');
            var p2 = arraySongs[cont].split('g')[1];
           p2 = parseInt(p2);
         $.ajax({
            cache:false,
            type:"GET",
            data:{p2:p2},
            url:"http://localhost/gpio2.php",
            success:function(msg){
                console.log("Connessione avvenuta!");
                console.log(msg);
        }
            });            
            audioElement.currentTime = pause_time;
            audioElement.volume = volume;
            audioElement.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
            prova = audioElement.duration;
             });
    audioElement.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
                 infoSong2();
             });
    audioElement.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function () {
            console.log("Audio load complete!");
            audioElement.play();
            });
            nextSong();
        }
        }
    }


        function nextSong (){
             if (cont < arraySongs.length) {
             audioElement.addEventListener('ended',function(){
                 cont++;
                 console.log("ArraySongs[cont]: "+arraySongs[cont]);
                 if(arraySongs[cont] == undefined)
                 {
                     var p5 = arraySongs[cont-1].split('g')[1];
                    console.log("Playlist complete!");
                    this.removeEventListener('ended', arguments.callee);
        repeatSong();
                 }else{
                 var p3 = arraySongs[cont].split('g')[1];
                 var p4 = arraySongs[cont-1].split('g')[1];

         $.ajax({
            cache:false,
            type:"GET",
            data:{p3:p3},
            url:"http://localhost/gpio2.php",
            success:function(msg){
                console.log("Connessione avvenuta! "+p3);
                console.log(msg);
        }
            });
             audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio/'+arraySongs[cont]+'.mp3');
    audioElement.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function () {
            audioElement.play();
            });
                 }
                })

             }  
        }
function jackInserted(){
        $.ajax({
            cache:false,
            type:"GET",
            url:"http://localhost/jack.php",
            success:function(msg){
                if(msg != 0)
                {
                    audioElement.pause();
                }else{
                    //stuff
                }        
        }
            });
    }
    setInterval(jackInserted,999);// The PHP page send me 1 if the jack is inserted, 0 if not.

function pauseSong(){
           audioElement.pause();
           pause_time = Math.floor(audioElement.currentTime);
    }
```

Comment: Heh. `minutesModafaka`, do you know them? That being said, where do you lose the second? In the shown `mm:ss`? Or do you actually lose a second of audible information (aka the song itself)?

Comment: I lose a second of the song itself

Comment: where is set `pause_time`?

Comment: @Kaiido I added the pauseSong function in the code